# Float値に対するfetch条件の生成について教えてください

Tags: swift, swift3, coredata

Float値に対するfetch条件の生成について教えてください。
Ingteger値に対しての条件設定は期待した結果が得られたのですが、Float値に対しての条件設定では期待した結果が得られませんでした。
Float値を検索する場合は別の方法があるのでしょうか？
もしくはFloat値のデータモデルに問題があるのでしょうか？

今更なのですが、やりたかったことに関して追記します。
SwiftのFloat型の精度の範囲の値をCoreDataを用いて永続化したデータを検索し、検索結果を得たい。
とてもシンプルな機能を想定していて、次のような内容は含みません。
 - プログラム内で数値計算等を行い、そこで得た値を永続化する。
 - プログラム内で数値計算等を行い、そこで得た値をkeyとする。
 - Float型の精度の範囲の値外の値をFloat型の値として、永続化および検索keyとする。
永続化および検索keyとして使用する値は、Float型の精度の範囲の値だけが対象です。

コードに不具合などありましたら教えてください。

(試した結果)

```
条件            |fetchされた値|コメント
===============+=============+=====================================
fvalue < 0.05  |0.05以下     |**0.05未満の値ではない。0.05もfetchされる。なぜ？**
fvalue <= 0.05 |0.05以下     |期待通り問題なし。
fvalue == 0.05 |             |**何もれられなかった。0.05が得られないのはなぜ？**
fvalue > 0.05  |0.06以上     |期待通り問題なし。
fvalue >= 0.05 |0.06以上     |**0.05以上の値ではない。0.05は得られない。なぜ？**
---------------+-------------+-------------------------------------
ivalue < 5     |5未満        |期待通り問題なし。
ivalue <= 5    |5以下        |期待通り問題なし。
ivalue == 5    |5            |期待通り問題なし。
ivalue > 5     |6以上        |期待通り問題なし。
ivalue >= 5    |5以上        |期待通り問題なし。
```

(Core model)

```
Entities:
Entity|Attribute|Type
======+=========+======
Pin   |name     |String
      |fvalue    |Float
      |ivalue    |Integer16
```

(code)

```
[AppDelegate.swift]
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    for i in 0..<10 {
        autoreleasepool { (result) in
            let pin = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Pin", into: managedObjectContext) as! Pin
            pin.name = "pin\(i)"
            pin.fvalue = NSNumber(value: Float(i) * 0.01)
            pin.ivalue = NSNumber(value: i)

            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSApplication.shared().presentError(nserror)
            }
        }
        managedObjectContext.refreshAllObjects()
    }

    do {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Pin")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "fvalue < 0.05")
        //fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ivalue < 5")
        let sortDiscriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDiscriptor]
        let pins = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Pin]
        for pin in pins {
            print("name: \(pin.name!), fvalue: \(pin.fvalue!), ivalue: \(pin.ivalue!)")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: 想定している機能について追記しました。

Comment: やりたいことを想定したコード示したつもりだったのですが、そのコード内のサンプルデータの生成を誤っていました。例えば、0.05を生成していいるつもりで Float(5) * 0.01 のようなコードを書いていました。
この演算で誤差を含んだ値を永続化してしまっていたため、fetchしたとき期待する結果を得られていませんでした。

Comment: 根本的な問題は永続化するための値の設定の仕方ではなく、等値判定の正確さが要求されるのにFloat型を使用していることです。なぜそこまでFloat型を使用することにこだわられるのでしょうか?例示されたコードのように絶対に0.05としか比較しないのならともかく、「プログラム内で数値計算等を行い」その結果をkeyとするのであれば、他にいくらでも誤差の影響を受ける場合が出てきます。

Comment: 質問内容に追記したのですが、プログラム内で数値計算で得られた値を扱うことを考えていないのに、サンプルコードとして示したコードでは数値計算を行なっていました。完全に私の過ちです。想定しているのは、例えばファイルに記録された値とか、UIから入力された値の計算機の扱える精度の範囲の値です。コメントに書いた「xxxのようなコードを書いていました」というのも数値計算等の結果を扱うことを想定していないのに数値計算をしているコードを示してしまった、と書いたつもりでいました。伝える努力が足りず申し訳けありませんでした。

Comment: その部分に関しては私の読み取りミスで「次のような内容は含みません」を完全に読み飛ばしていたようです。失礼しました。ただし、それにしても、Float型を使い続けようとする姿勢は全く理解できません。極めて限定的な条件でしか動かないことがわかっていながら、それよりさらに極めて小さな範囲のテストをしただけで、なぜFloat型の使用を強行するのですか?そんな苦労をしておびえながら使わなくても、根本的な解決策が目の前にあるのですよ。

Comment: 確かにFloat, Doubleを使うことには気を使います。簡単なコードでさえこの有様です。Float値にこだわっているのではなく、回答を頂いたdecimalでの永続化は出来るなら避けたいと考えています。もちろん期待する結果が得られないのであれば使います。避けたい理由一つはdecimalにすることでデータ容量がどのくらい増えるのか見積もれていないことです。decimal型というのは何バイトのデータ型でしょうか？　固定長のデータではなく桁数に応じて増えるようなものを調べもせず勝手に想像しています。

Comment: Decimal型の内部表現となる`NSDecimal`(Swift 3では`Decimal`)型は20バイトの固定長です。`Float`の4バイトと比べれば少々増えますが、全てのカラムをdecimalにするのでなければ、Core Dataを使うような用途で問題になることはあまりないだろうと思います。データ量が数万件を超える場合、速度面での不安が出るかもしれませんが(ただし、単に「不安」だけで採用を見送るのではなくきちんとデータを取ることをお勧めします)、もし、decimalで速度面の要件を満たせないのであれば、スケール表現を採用してinteger 32 (`Int32`)にしてしまう手もあります。Floatと同じデータ量で、floatより高速です。明確な理由もなく「decimalでの永続化は出来るなら‌​避けたい」と考えるよりも、明確な理由のある「Floatでの等値比較は **絶対に** 避けたい」と考えていただきたいところです。

Answer (score 0):

Core Dataのfetch方法の問題ではなく、2進浮動小数点数の問題です。

あなたと同じ結果は、Core Dataを使用しなくても、再現できます。

(2進浮動小数点数の問題を論ずるのにちょうど良いので、`0..<10`ではなく、`0...10`にしてあります。)

```
import Foundation

let floatArr: [NSNumber] = (0...10).map{NSNumber(value: Float($0) * 0.01)}
print(floatArr) //-> [0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09999999]
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF < 0.05")
print(floatArr.filter{predicate.evaluate(with: $0)}) //-> [0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF <= 0.05")
print(floatArr.filter{predicate.evaluate(with: $0)}) //-> [0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF == 0.05")
print(floatArr.filter{predicate.evaluate(with: $0)}) //-> []
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF > 0.05")
print(floatArr.filter{predicate.evaluate(with: $0)}) //-> [0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09999999]
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF >= 0.05")
print(floatArr.filter{predicate.evaluate(with: $0)}) //-> [0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09999999]
```

`0.01`のように10進法で有限の桁数で表現出来る小数も、2進法で表現すると無限小数(循環小数)になります。(`_`は何か数字が入るのではなく、単に繰り返しの範囲を表しています。)

0.00_00001010001111010111_00001010001111010111_00001010001111010111_...

`Float`型ではこのうち24bit(最初の`1`と続く23bit)を使い、残りの桁は丸められてしまうので、`Float`型でこの値を精確に表現することはできません。

上記で10番目の値が`0.1`ではなく`0.09999999`と表示されているのにはお気づきだと思いますが、`0.05`と表示されている5番目の値も実際には`0.05`ではありません。

```
print(Float(5) * 0.01 - 0.05) //-> -3.72529e-09
```

(上記の例の場合、`0.05`は理論上の精確な値の**0.05**を表すのではなく、`0.05`と言う10進表記に一番近い`Float`型の値を表すのですが、`Float(5) * 0.01`はそれとも一致しません。)

`NSNumber`型を10進数の文字列として表示する際には四捨五入により一見正しい値を保持しているように見えるのですが、`Float`型としての値は実際にはそれらの値を精確には表せていないのです。

`debugPrint`を使うと、そのような微小な差異を出来るだけ10進表示にも反映して表示してくれます。

```
for i in 0...10 {
    debugPrint(Float(i) * 0.01)
}
```

**0.0

0.00999999978

0.0199999996

0.0299999993

0.0399999991

0.049999997

0.0599999987

0.0700000003

0.0799999982

0.0899999961

0.099999994**

---

***もしくはFloat値のデータモデルに問題があるのでしょうか？***

上記で示したように、10進表現の小数で境界値を精確に指定する必要のある用途では、2進浮動小数点型のfloatやdoubleを使用せずに、**必ずdecimalを使用してください**(コード側では`NSNumber`ではなく`NSDecimalNumber`)。

Answer (score -2):

二進数の実数値扱いに問題があるとの指摘を頂きましたので、試行錯誤の結果、質問に挙げたコードを以下のように修正することにしました。この場合は動いていそうですが、精度の問題つきまとうのでしょうね。

(coredataへの値の設定)

```
pin.fvalue = NSNumber(value: Float(Double(i) * 0.01))
```

(prediateの生成)

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "fvalue = %f", 0.05)
```

---

以下、試行錯誤の一部

二進数の実数値扱いに問題があるとの指摘を頂いたので実数値の扱いについて試行してみました。

(1) 質問で提示したコードと同様の場合

```
let f1 = Float(5) * 0.01
let fn1 = NSNumber(value: f1)
```

デバッガで値を見てみると以下の通りでした。
f1  Float   0.049999997
fn1 NSNumber    Float(0.050000)

(2) 定数の場合

```
let f2 = 0.05
let fn2 = NSNumber(value: f2)
```

f2  Double  0.050000000000000003
fn2 NSNumber    Double(0.05)

Doubleとして扱われるようです。

(3)　整数と実数の演算結果では。変数の整数と実数の演算は型変換を行う必要がありますが、定数は演算できるのですね。

```
let f3 = 5 * 0.01
let fn3 = NSNumber(value: f3)
```

f3  Double  0.050000000000000003
fn3 NSNumber    Double(0.05)
(1)ではFloatと定数の演算ではFloatになっていましたが、結果はDoubleとなってます。

(4) (3)の結果から、FloatではなくDoubleに合わせることに。

```
let f4 = Double(5) * 0.01
let fn4 = NSNumber(value: f4)
```

f4  Double  0.050000000000000003
fn4 NSNumber    Double(0.05)

```
(5) NSNumberへはFloatで。
let f5 = Double(5) * 0.01
let fn5 = NSNumber(value: Float(f5))
```

f5  Double  0.050000000000000003
fn5 NSNumber    Float(0.050000)

Comment: **_精度の問題つきまとうのでしょうね_** その通りですね。掲載の方法では「`0.05`を`Float`に変換した時の値(にできるだけ近い値、例示の数値の場合は全く同じになる)を`fvalue`に設定している」だけで何も根本的な解決にはなっていません。「`Double`経由の値を設定していれば大丈夫なんだ」なんて勘違いをして、`NSPredicate(format: "fvalue * 20 == %f", 1.0)`なんて条件を使う人が出れば途端に破綻します。致命的なバグを混入させてしまう前に、根本的な解決を図ることをお勧めします。

Comment: 今回扱おうとしている実数値はfloatの精度で十分な値で、プログラム内での演算値でもないので大丈夫だと思っています。質問の例にした　pin.fvalue = NSNumber(value: Float(i) * 0.01)　は、できるだけ近い値としてさえ設定できていませんでした。勉強になりました。